# schemagen ant task is not creating the namespace in the xsd

Tags: jax-ws

Schemagen ant task is not generating the namespace in the generated XSD file.

In src folder there are 5 classes in the same package "com.test"
Can somebody suggest me to solve this issuethe options.
Regards,
Jayakrishna

Answer (score 0):

You should post some example code regarding you classes. For now I am guesing that you might want to add a `package-info.java` file to the package and add a `@XmlSchema` annotation. Like so:

```
    @XmlSchema(namespace = "http://your.name.space/definition")
    package com.test;
```

Does that help?